# angular event doesn't update page

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript

I'm converting a page in a mvc application with a lot of inline jquery javascript to angular using typescript.

The first calls works fine but I have a problem: based on a selection in a dropdown, the event  updates several controls in the view, make a few ajax calls and finally update the view with the data from the calls.

Seems the conversion is working fine, but at the end of the call the page isn't updated.

1. I tried to remove all the old jquery code to avoid problems.
2. batarang and java console reports no errors.
3. the final ajax call is done and the result shown in a debug.

All seems to work fine, but the page isn't updated.

How can I find the problem?

thanks

Comment: `All seems to work fine, but the page isn't updated.` seems like a `scope.$apply` problem. Use angular's `$http` instead of `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are not handling your asynchronous calls correctly. It's impossible to tell from your question but it is a very common mistake with symptoms as you describe.

Make sure you are updating your model within the `.then()` method of a promise returned from an `$http` request. For example

```
someFnDoingHttpRequest().then(function(data){ 
        // updated the model with the data 
        })
```

Also (another common mistake) make sure `someFnDoingHttpRequest()` returns a promise.

Comment: yes, this was the problem... I used $q to handle the async request and now is working quite fine ... I have only the problem that I would like to show an animated gif at the beginning of the update and hide t the end, but doesn't work

Comment: Show your animation (e.g. `showAnimation(true)`) immediately before calling `someFnDoingHttpRequest` and then `showAnimation(false)` immediately after you update your model.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any code, it's difficult to answer but if you bind an event to an element and want to update something in the callback, you will have to use $apply

```
scope.$apply(function () {
    // your code
});
```

$apply will trigger a $digest cycle, and should be used when you want to update something while being outside angular's context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "find the problem" then you can use the following option.

1. Go to **Internet Explorer (10 or 11)**.
2. Select "**Internet Options**" from the settings menu.
3. Go to the "**Advanced**" tab (the last tab)
4. Settings are listed and **select** "**Display a notification about every script error**"
5. **Deselect** the "**Disable Script debugging (Internet Explorer)**" and "**Disable script debugging (Other)**"
6. Run the program again, you will get notification about the real issue that happens while displaying actual result.